# Does a MongoDB Capped Collection lock a database when it reaches the cap?

Tags: mongodb

Once a collection reaches it's cap limit, does mongodb issue a lock for every insert, as it needs to make room for it?

Comment: It will issue a lock when it inserts anyway

Answer (score 0):

As @Sammaye correctly pointed out, the lock will be issued.

As you can see from [this docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/#which-operations-lock-the-database):

it is written that an insert will initiated write lock for a normal collection, and because [Capped collection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/) can be seen as ordinary collection, there will be lock on any insert.

> Insert data   Write lock